# Getting error "package 'visual c# project system' has failed to load properly"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I recently started my visual studio and its showing an error in message box with ff msg: -

```
Package 'Visual C# Project System' Has Failed To Load Properly (Guid = {Fae04Ec1-301F-11D3-Bf4B-00C04F79Efbc}
```

Can any one help me out with this. I dont want the solution I want the reason why this error is coming?

Comment: Because your installation is corrupt. Not sure why you're uninterested in the solution, but in case you decide to care, it's to reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: @ Code Gray it was working last day??? but today its giving error. uninterested in solution is because  i can reinstall it and it gonna work. but knowing the reson why it occurs helps me to understand its internals. i want to work in visual studio rather then work on.

Comment: @vote down why vote down can u explain?

Comment: Hard to say. I'm not very good at answering questions where people aren't interested in the solution. Have you messed with the assemblies in the GAC between the time it stopped working? Or installed any add-ons or extensions? Something is clearly corrupt; it's impossible to say what without more information.

Comment: This happened to me when I had installed an IE 8 install (upgrading system from IE 6) but had not rebooted yet.

Comment: @WarrenP did you make sure about mscoree.dll???

Comment: Yes. Everything was fine except that a reboot was needed probably due to some MSCOREE typelibrary registrations.

Comment: i guess your mscoree.dll is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the cause of the error; it was because of mscoree.dll. I found mscoree.dll
was not in the system32 folder. I just placed it there and everything started working. Whenever you come across such errors make sure that you have mscoree.dll in the right place. Some programmers normally just try reinstalling the application whatever the error may be without knowing its cause. I would not recommend reinstalling the whole Visual Studio rather just download mscoree.dll and place it in the right folder (system 32). That's it.

Comment: So now the question is, **who moved `mscoree.dll`**? That shouldn't ever get moved from where it's supposed to be. You can't just go dragging random system files from place to place, even when it appears to fix your problem. That indicates that your .NET Framework installation is corrupt. I highly suggest that you reinstall it, despite your insinuation that us reinstallers are silly. I like my system to be stable; your mileage may vary.

Comment: i didnt mean that reinstalling is silly. If going for it without knowing anything then i would prefer exploring a bit. This is the error caused due to mscoree.dll. i observed it, its working fine. Reinstalling depends on the kind of work you doing with it. i am using it just for learning so i prefer exploring but if i have some important work with it i would have prefer reinstalling. So depends on the situation you are in. isnt it????

Comment: How did you find out it was `mscoree.dll`? I’m having the same issue as you but that DLL is present, so maybe another one is causing issues, but I have no idea which one.

Comment: @SamHocevar I am not so sure as its a really old post. Now I am completely working with java from past 4 years. However you can give it a try and check whether it worked or not.